# How to rewrite row id from tail to head with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to reverse the whole table of id from head most becomes a tail most. For example. I have 10 rows in a table. I need to convert the 10th to 1st and 1st to 10th - order by datetime. Also the structure and data still remains.

*I don't know how to ask a question like this. So sorry for those whom my question looks stupid or attempt-less to you.*

**SRC TABLE**

```
+----+------+-------------------+
| id | item |      dtime        |
+----+------+-------------------+
| 1  |  J   |  2017-10-10 10:10 |
+----+------+-------------------+
| 2  |  I   |  2017-10-10 10:09 |
+----+------+-------------------+
| 3  |  H   |  2017-10-10 10:08 |
+----+------+-------------------+
.
.
.
+----+------+-------------------+
| 10 |  A   |  2017-10-10 10:01 |
+----+------+-------------------+
```

**EXPECTED**

```
+----+------+-------------------+
| id | item |      dtime        |
+----+------+-------------------+
| 1  |  A   |  2017-10-10 10:01 |
+----+------+-------------------+
| 2  |  B   |  2017-10-10 10:02 |
+----+------+-------------------+
| 3  |  C   |  2017-10-10 10:03 |
+----+------+-------------------+
.
.
.
+----+------+-------------------+
| 10 |  J   |  2017-10-10 10:10 |
+----+------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Add `ORDER BY dtime` to your query?

Comment: No, I need the number of `id` change not `order by` it.

Comment: The real question here is : Why?

Comment: Because the original `csv` is not sort. When I import into mysql it's shuffled. So I need to re-arrange it by date.

Comment: But you can always add a sorting to your query, no?

Comment: If you really need to do this, I'd recommend creating a new temporary table, and selecting the values from the original to populate it, resetting the id values as it does so

Comment: Create a new table, insert into that table the properly sorted selected data, drop the original table.

Comment: @rndus2r, I also need to display the ID in a table to reference it as well.

Comment: @David, how to tell sql to write the ordery comparing by dtime? Which is first?

Comment: Then do it as others have suggested - select item and dtime ordered by dtime, replace id with an auto increment value, insert it into new table and drop old table

Comment: @Wilf: By adding `ORDER BY dtime` to your `SELECT`.  For reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @David, with all my respect. I still not get it. Could you please explain?

Comment: I'm still wondering why it matters.

Comment: Ok, when these data display in a table. The 1st row will be the most recent and the last one is the oldest. Doesn't it make sense to you why the latest row is the oldest instead of newest?

Comment: No. MySQL has no row order, so it does not matter. Why should it matter?

Comment: It sounds like the generated system identifier matters to the users.  It shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you have is a table of imported data where the import was incorrect and, for whatever reason, you need to re-import the data to generate new identifiers.  (Though your user output *really* shouldn't depend so much on the identifiers.  It sounds like you're misusing system identifiers.)  But the original source of data is gone and you need to re-import from the table you have.

While I still find it *highly suspect* that you might not actually need to do this (*especially* if other data already relies on the identified records), at a *technical* level there isn't much to it.

First, create a new table with the same structure as the existing table.  Then you can insert into that new table a selected set of data from the existing table.  Something as simple as:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (item, dtime)
  SELECT item, dtime FROM OldTable ORDER BY dtime
```

The `AUTOINCREMENT` identifier in the new table would generate your new `id` values.  Then you can drop the old table.

If necessary, rename the new table to the original table's name.

Comment: David, this is what I'm talking about. Sorry that my problem looks annoying to you. But I don't like the way data arrange randomly in the table. The latest row must continue with the newer ones. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Wilf: It's not that the problem "looks annoying", it's that we suspect the design is relying on something that is fundamentally incorrect and will cause you further problems.

Comment: David, these data will display in `dataTables` and I'd like it to sort by id rather than datetime. Which is display as `Jan 12, 2016` for the easy readable. And to me, this is the easiest way to sort those thousands of rows by id than date.

Comment: If it is just about *displaying* you don't need to change anything at all... just query with `ORDER BY` and in your script which displays the result echo an incremental id. That would be way safer.